# c# Change the status of a button after closing a form?

Tags: c#, forms, button

this is my problem: I have a  main form where I have a panel that contains some buttons, when the user clicks a button a form is opened.( I have some buttons and clicking these buttons the user can open  different forms )If the user click again the same button he can close the form.
this is what I do:

in the main form I have a method that is invoked when one of these  buttons is clicked by the user, the method checks the text associated to the button in order to decide which is the button clicked. Once I have discovered which is the button that has been clicked it launches the form associated with the button.

this is the code

```
private void tlStBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        //// loop through all items in the ToolStrip
        //foreach (Object item in toolStripMain.Items)
        //{
        //    // if this item is a ToolStripButton object, check it
        //    if (item is ToolStripButton)
        //    {
        //        // cast the item to a ToolStripButton object and check it if the sender of the event is the currently looked at button in the loop
        //        ToolStripButton button = (ToolStripButton)item;
        //        button.Checked = (button == sender);
        //    }
        //}

        foreach (ToolStripItem item in this.VerticalToolBox.Items)
        {
            if ((item != sender) &&
                (item is ToolStripButton))
            {
                ((ToolStripButton)item).Checked = false;
            }
        }

        if (sender_old != sender)
        {
            sender_old = sender;
            if ((sender as ToolStripButton).Text == "Protection")
            {
                if (!Application.OpenForms.OfType<frm_Protection>().Any())
                {
                    frm_Protection Newf = new frm_Protection(ref CurrentProject);
                    Newf.Show();

               }
            }
            else
            {
                if (Application.OpenForms.OfType<frm_Protection>().Any())
                {
                    Application.OpenForms.OfType<frm_Protection>().First().Close();
                    Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
                }
                GC.Collect();
                GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
            }

                if ((sender as ToolStripButton).Text == "Info")
                {
                    if (!Application.OpenForms.OfType<Frm_ObjectInfo>().Any())
                    {
                        Frm_ObjectInfo Newform = new Frm_ObjectInfo();
                        Newform.Show();
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if (Application.OpenForms.OfType<Frm_ObjectInfo>().Any())
                    {
                        Application.OpenForms.OfType<Frm_ObjectInfo>().First().Close();
                        Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
                    }

                    GC.Collect();
                    GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
                }

            if ((sender as ToolStripButton).Text == "Layers")
            {
                if (!Application.OpenForms.OfType<Frm_LayersManage>().Any())
                {
                    Frm_LayersManage Newform = new Frm_LayersManage();
                    Newform.Show();
                    Application.OpenForms.OfType<Frm_LayersManage>().First().UpdateLayers(null, CurrentProject.layers);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (Application.OpenForms.OfType<Frm_LayersManage>().Any())
                {
                    Application.OpenForms.OfType<Frm_LayersManage>().First().Close();
                    Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
                    UpdateScreen = true;
                }

                GC.Collect();
                GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
            }

            if (Properties.Settings.Default.Grip2Enabled && (sender as ToolStripButton).Text == "Insert Grip")
            {
                gbx_SelectGrip.Visible = true;

            }
            else
            {
                gbx_SelectGrip.Visible = false;
            }

            //SelectedPoints.Clear();
            //MousePointList.Clear();
            //myIDs.Clear();
            //IdxPointsEnt.Clear();
            //RatiosLines.Clear();
            //CadSource.cuts_tmp.Clear();
            //IDAddedCutList.Clear();
            //ZoomPort.SetValue(0, 0);
            //ZoomPort.SetValue(0, 1);
            //ZoomPort.SetValue(0, 2);
            //ZoomPort.SetValue(0, 3);

            //// Reset index of scrap selected by moving gripper
            //idxScrap = -1;
            //pnl_OpenTK.Refresh();

            //// Se ho evidenziato uno SCRAP , annullo l'evidenziazione.
            //if (IdsScrapDisablePath[0] != -1)
            //{
            //    int identifiedScrap = CadSource.IdToIdx_Scrap(IdsScrapDisablePath[0]);

            //    if (CadSource.scraps[identifiedScrap].GripExists())
            //    {
            //       CadSource.scraps[identifiedScrap].Enabled = ScrapAbilitation.Enabled;     // Disable clicked scrap
            //    }
            //    else
            //    {
            //       CadSource.scraps[identifiedScrap].Enabled = ScrapAbilitation.WithoutGrip;     // Disable clicked scrap
            //    }
            //}
            //numScrap = 0;
            //IdsScrapDisablePath = new List<int>() { -1, -1 };

        }
        else
        {
            (sender as ToolStripButton).Checked = false;
            (sender as ToolStripButton).BackColor = Color.Transparent;

            sender_old = new object() { };
            if (Application.OpenForms.OfType<frm_Protection>().Any())
            {

                Application.OpenForms.OfType<frm_Protection>().First().Close();
                Properties.Settings.Default.Save();

            }


            if (Application.OpenForms.OfType<Frm_ObjectInfo>().Any())
            {
                Application.OpenForms.OfType<Frm_ObjectInfo>().First().Close();
                Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
            }

            if (Application.OpenForms.OfType<Frm_LayersManage>().Any())
            {
                Application.OpenForms.OfType<Frm_LayersManage>().First().Close();
                Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
            }

            gbx_SelectGrip.Visible = false;

            GC.Collect();
            GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
        }

        SelectedPoints.Clear();
        MousePointList.Clear();
        myIDs.Clear();
        IdxPointsEnt.Clear();
        RatiosLines.Clear();
        CurrentProject.cuts_tmp.Clear();
        IDAddedCutList.Clear();
        ZoomPort.SetValue(0, 0);
        ZoomPort.SetValue(0, 1);
        ZoomPort.SetValue(0, 2);
        ZoomPort.SetValue(0, 3);

        // Reset index of scrap selected by moving gripper
        idxScrap = -1;
        pnl_OpenTK.Refresh();

        // Se ho evidenziato uno SCRAP , annullo l'evidenziazione.
        if (IdsScrapDisablePath[0] != -1)
        {
            int identifiedScrap = CurrentProject.IdToIdx_Scrap(IdsScrapDisablePath[0]);

            if (CurrentProject.scraps[identifiedScrap].GripExists())
            {
                CurrentProject.scraps[identifiedScrap].Enabled = ScrapAbilitation.Enabled;     // Disable clicked scrap
            }
            else
            {
                CurrentProject.scraps[identifiedScrap].Enabled = ScrapAbilitation.WithoutGrip;     // Disable clicked scrap
            }
        }
        numScrap = 0;
        IdsScrapDisablePath = new List<int>() { -1, -1 };
  }
```

the forms that are opned clicking the buttons are forms where I have set the controlbox at false because I don't want that the user is able to close the forms without clicking again the button that has clicked to open it, but I have found a problem because if the user closes the form in this way (see the picture below) the status of the button remains checked but the form has been closed manually

[image: this is how the user can close the from manually]

To solve this problem I have thought to add this method associated to the event closing of my forms this is the code

```
 private void frm_Protection_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
    {
        ////// if user closes manually the window without using the button I have to change the state of the button

       Frm_Main f = new Frm_Main();
        f = Application.OpenForms.OfType<Frm_Main>().Last();
        f.tlsBut_Protection.Checked = false;

    }
```

with this code if I close manually the form the status of the button it becomes false again in the main form
but I have discovered that It causes some problems to my program , one of this problem is that after closing the form if I click again the button it seems that the method associated to the clicking event is not called  and the form is not opened I have to click it twice before it works again.

do you know why what do I do in the wrong way???

thanks for your help

Answer (score 3):

To prevent a Form from closing, you can subscribe to the `FormClosing` event, which fires *before* the Form closes, and intercept (and cancel) the user's action.

```
private void frm_Protection_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CloseReason == CloseReason.UserClosing)
        e.Cancel = true;
}
```

Unfortunately, clicking the "X" (in the Taskbar preview or in the program itself) and calling `this.Close()` are both treated as "UserClosing" close reasons, so we need to modify it slightly.

Add a property to `frm_Protection`, and use that to determine whether the Form can be closed:

```
public bool CanClose { private get; set; }

private void frm_Protection_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    e.Cancel = !CanClose;
}
```

And then only set the property to `true` when you want to allow the Form to be closed:

```
var frmP = Application.OpenForms.OfType<frm_Protection>().FirstOrDefault();

if (frmP != null)
{
    frmP.CanClose = true;
    frmP.Close();
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer but it doesn't work because in this way I can't close the from in anyway even when I want to